# E=MC^2, Are we/the universe just potential momentum force?

Tags: states-of-matter

I am not a physicist, but am curious. If the famous equation e=mc^2 is to be taken literally. As E is in joules and is taken as the force required to move an object x distance. What are we, and what is everything in the universe, just a blurb (ha)? 
I further refer to the anahilation of matter into energy by a process such as applies in a nuclear explosion (bomb), where matter (U235) is turned into its energy state. Clearly I don't know, but want an explanation. Please forgive unimportant inaccuracies.
Appreciate all answers.

Comment: Simplest impossible: if you mix an amount of $m/2$ matter with $m/2$ antimatter, you will generate an explosion of energy $E$, in joules in the amount of $mc^2$ and nothing of the original matter nor antimatter will be left.

Comment: An incomplete and this false equation is never to be taken for anything but incomplete and this false.

Comment: it is a metaphor

Comment: Please do not attempt to use answers post as part of a conversational system. "Answer"s are only for answering the question.

Answer (score 2):

- "potential momentum force" are just 3 words, if you put them together, you get only a tag cloud.
- You don't need force to "move an object to an x distance". (More exactly, you can move it with an infinitesimal small force to anywhere, if you have enough time.) You need force if you want to move it to a higher energy.
- In an U235 explosion, only a very little bit of the matter is tranformed to photons. Photons have energy.

Unfortunately I can't understand more in your question which could be answerable.

Comment: @Wolphramjonny Ok, but you can move it with infinitesimal small force to anywhere, if you have enough time. I insert it into the answer.